# How to manage and display Webassembly Gui app in Next.js

Tags: javascript, user-interface, rust, next.js, webassembly

I have compiled a Gui app to Wasm file, together with a generated JS file.

The Wasm file actually contains one **infinite loop** function `fn start() -> void` that display a 3D animation.

#### The problem is

1. Although calling `wasm.start()` can display the animation, it is out of control. **The animation will display in all the pages**. How can I restrict it within one particular component?
2. The animation window loses interactive ability. **It can't respond to mouse and keyboard any longer as it should do**. What is the correct way to start the animation?
3. I have to call `start` within a `try-catch` scope, or otherwise the compiler reports errors. Why?

Currently what I did looks like

```js
// second_page.tsx

export default function SecondPage() {
// ... something else

const startWasm = async () => {
        try {
            start()           // this function is imported from the Wasm 
        } catch (error) {
        }
    }

//... something else

return <h1>Second Post
        <div >
             <button onClick={() => startWasm()}>     // OnClick of the button
                      Click to Start
            </button>
        </div>
        <h2>
            <Link href="/">
                <a>Back to home</a>
            </Link>
        </h2>

    </h1 >;
}
}
```

Comment: What GUI library are you using? Typically they have documentation for targeting WASM if its supported. In general though, your code shouldn't infinitely loop, but rather render in callbacks driven by `window.requestAnimationFrame()`.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for replying and classifying the problem, I will then try searching ` requestAnimationFrame`.  I was using [Bevy](https://crates.io/crates/bevy) in which I failed to find a tutorial on embedding the generated wasm as if it was trivial. Btw, does callback rendering require any change for corperation on the Rust side?

Comment: Ah bevy, I'd wager consuming the whole webpage is the extent of their out-of-the-box support for wasm at the moment. Though I encourage you to reach out to the developers on one of their [community](https://bevyengine.org/community/) channels (like github, reddit, or discord). I bet someone at least has some tips.

Comment: @kmdreko ok, from what you said I think embedding bevy into webpage is not a good idea, for now at least. Thanks very much.